# line-height ignored when image is in the text

Tags: css

I'm trying to display a text in a div

```
<div style='line-height: 16px;'>$text</div>
```

The 16px line height is OK until I put some images into the $text (basically I replace the smiley signs with 15px high smiley images). In this case the line-height become 19px.
How can I force the lines to keep the 16px height regardless if there is image or not?
(margin, padding, border: 0px for each elements)

example here:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;}

div.comment_text {
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  line-height: 16px;
  overflow: auto;}
</style>

<div class='comment_text' style='top: 20px;'>
  the measured line height here 16px which is OK
  <br/><a href="mailto:myaddress@gmail.com" target='_blank'>myaddress@gmail.com</a>
  <br/><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target='_blank'>http://www.facebook.com</a>
  <br/>this
  <br/>lines
  <br/>are
  <br/>for
  <br/>example
  <br/>to
  <br/>demonstrate
  <br/>my
  <br/>problem
</div>    

<div class='comment_text' style='top: 300px;'>
  <img class='relative' style='top: 0px; max-height: 16px;' src='../images/smileys/tongue_out.png'/> the measured line-height here 17px which is wrong
  <br/>i'm a 15px high image: <img class='relative' style='top: 0px; max-height:16px;' src='../images/smileys/grinning.png'/>
  <br/>me too: <img class='relative' style='top: 0px; max-height: 16px;' src='../images/smileys/winking.png'/>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not ignored...it's just that the images--if taller than the font--will push it apart as needed.

Comment: they are not taller. line-height: 16px, height of images: 15px

Comment: They're taller than your *font-size* which is at 12pt. 12pt type set with 16pt line-height will add 2pt of space above and below the type (16-12 = 4. 4/2 = 2px above and below). With a 15px image in the mix, you now end up with 2px above and below that for a total of 19px (15 + 2 + 2).

Comment: OK, thanks. So what is the solution if I want to keep the 12px font size and use my images?

Comment: see my answer below. I posted some example markup for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't ignore your line height.

The issue is that your inline image is taller than your font size.

Line height is calculated by taking the line height, and if it's taller than the font size, subtracting the font-size and then splitting it in half to add space above and below.

So, you have:

(16px line-height) - (12px font-size) = 4px

That means each line of text will have 2px above and 2px below.

The problem you have is that you've added a 15px image to the line. 15px + 2px above + 2px below = 19px. So that's going to push that one line further apart.

The fix is to make sure your inline element is no taller than your font-size. If you still want to use a larger icon, then you have to make an empty inline element with overflow set to visible, and then place your image inside of that.

Example: http://jsbin.com/yijuyepi/2/

Comment: Identifying the leading is the right idea but is not correctly applied. The upper half leading is not applied to img element just the text. The height comes from the 15px of the img above the baseline + 2px for the descender below the baseline of the text + 2px for the lower half leading on the text. The issue can therefore be resolved by taking the image off the baseline. i.e. `img { vertical-align:bottom; }`

Comment: @Alohci true, that solution would work in this particular case. But isn't quite as scalable as there'd still be a smaller height limit.

Comment: @DA. thank you for the solution and the detailed explanation. one more thing: is that two pixel high spacing is a constant value?

Comment: @tcxbalage not sure what you mean by 'constant value'. The 2px comes from taking the line-height, subtracting the font-size, and dividing that by 2 (to split it above and below the text).

Comment: sorry, I was too tired, obviously you already explained that too in your answer, I just haven't paid enough attention :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `max-height: 16px` to the images, to avoid making them separate the lines if they are taller.

Comment: no luck, there is still 18px between the lines if both lines has images

Comment: @tcxbalage Can you post a demo?